# enviar una pk de un objeto a un createview como fk del otro objeto

Tags: python, django, apk

**models**

```
class Mascota(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    raza = models.ForeignKey(Raza, null=False, blank=False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(ColorMascota, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genero = models.ForeignKey(GeneroMascota, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_nac = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    marca_visible = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    alergias = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    peso = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    registro = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    observaciones = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, null=False,blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class FichaServicio(models.Model):
    mascota = models.ForeignKey(Mascota, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_in = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    fecha_out = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    servicio = models.ManyToManyField(TipoServicio, null=False, blank=True)
    peso = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    observaciones = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

**views**

```
class FichaVacunaList(ListView):
    model = FichaVacuna
    template_name = 'vacuna/fichavacuna_list.html'
class FichaVacuna(CreateView):
    model = FichaVacuna
    form_class = FichaVacunaForm
    template_name = 'vacuna/fichavacuna_form.html'
    success_url = '/mascota/vaclist'
```

**urls**

```
url(r'^vaclist$', FichaVacunaList.as_view(), name='fichavacuna_list'),
url(r'^vaccreate$', FichaVacuna.as_view(), name='fichavacuna_create'),
```

quiero mandar el id de mascota desde MascotaList para crear una nueva ficha de vacunacion pero convirtiendo ese id en fk del fichaVacuna.
Mi pregunta es si se puede y como hacerlo ya que estoy iniciando

Comment: La idea es una Mascota tiene una FichaVacuna ? y al momento de crear una mascota deseas enviar la id de fichavacuna ?

Comment: Dónde es´ta tu modelo FichaVacuna ?

Comment: Puedes enviarlo por parámetros post o get

Comment: Tegito123, si esa es la idea ya que la ficha es un servicio o una vacuna que se aplica a esa mascota

Comment: class FichaVacuna(models.Model):
 masctoa = models.ForeignKey(Mascota, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 fecha_vac = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
 vacuna = models.ForeignKey(TipoVacuna, null=False,blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 fecha_proxima = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

Comment: encontre como hacerlo con createview en otro ejemplo pero no me funciona, y por el metodo post o get algun ejemplo para guiarme

Comment: saludos como tienes tu form ?

Comment: ya lo soluciones usando pahtname en javascript, Gracias por sus comentarios